# wordpress customizer get_theme_mod no output

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i am working on a theme for wordpress right now to see how it works etc. But now i want to implement some customizer settings/controls. So here is what i tried

```
    function myfirsttheme_customizer_register($wp_customize){
        $wp_customize->add_section('mycustomtheme_colors', array(
        'title' => __('Colors','mycustomtheme'),
        'description' => 'Modify the theme colors'
        )); 

        $wp_customize->add_setting('background_color', array(
        'default' => '#fff',
        )); 

        $wp_customize->add_setting('link_color', array(
        'default' => '#4b4b4',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'background_color', array(
        'label' => __('Edit Background Color', 'mycustomtheme'),
        'section' => 'mycustomtheme_colors',
        'settings' => 'background_color'
        ) ));

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link-color', array(
        'label' => __('Edit Link Color', 'mycustomtheme'),
        'section' => 'mycustomtheme_colors',
        'settings' => 'link_color'
        ) ));
    }
add_action('wp_head','mycustomtheme_css_customizer');
add_action('customize_register','myfirsttheme_customizer_register');
```

and the HTML/CSS here

```
function mycustomtheme_css_customizer(){
    ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        article { background-color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('background_color');?> ; }
    </style>

    <?php
}
```

So when i change the line `echo get_theme_mod('background_color');` with an actual color like `#fff` it works fine, but for some reason the `get_theme_mod` doesn't give an output and i can't understand why not.

Comment: check out this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90942/issue-with-get-theme-mod-returning-a-blank-value-instead-of-the-saved-value

Answer (score 0):

add these line in your setting array

`'type' => 'theme_mod',
 'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',`

following code will work

```
 function myfirsttheme_customizer_register($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_section('mycustomtheme_colors', array(
    'title' => __('Colors','mycustomtheme'),
    'description' => 'Modify the theme colors'
    )); 

    $wp_customize->add_setting('background_color', array(
    'default' => '#fff',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options'
    )); 

    $wp_customize->add_setting('link_color', array(
    'default' => '#4b4b4',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'background_color', array(
    'label' => __('Edit Background Color', 'mycustomtheme'),
    'section' => 'mycustomtheme_colors',
    'settings' => 'background_color'
    ) ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link-color', array(
    'label' => __('Edit Link Color', 'mycustomtheme'),
    'section' => 'mycustomtheme_colors',
    'settings' => 'link_color'
    ) ));
}

add_action('customize_register','myfirsttheme_customizer_register');
```

Comment: I copy&pasted  your code but i still doesn't work :/